# Is there a way to find or ascertain date or time format from a given value in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to build a filter for date and time datatype columns which checks if all the values in that column follow the same format. Suppose we have date of birth, in Row1 it's saved as 1998-02-18 (%Y-%m-%d) and in Row2 value is 14-03-2020 (%d-%m-%Y), Row3 is 12/05/2001 (%d/%m/%Y). All are correct date formats, but I want check if they are all uniform or not. So if I have a given date, say 1998-02-18, is there any function or way to get (%Y-%m-%d) as result? that can be used to compare with other formats.

Comment: They are not correct date formats.  BigQuery has a very nice data type called `date` to support date columns.  Anything else is just a string.  You should fix the data.

Comment: Hi, I'm talking about **date** datetype only, Is it not possible to have more than one date formats in a **date** datatype column?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if some values cannot be converted using `safe.parse_date()`.  The following gets exceptions for a particular pattern:

```
select datecol
from t
where datecol is not null and
      safe.parse_date('%Y-%m-%d', col) is null;
```

Note that if you have different formats, you can try them out:

```
select coalesce(safe.parse_date('%Y-%m-%d', col),
                safe.parse_date('%d-%m-%Y', col),
                safe.parse_date('%m-%d-%Y', col)
               )
```

Note that this will likely produce incorrect values, because date strings are ambiguous, unless you know the format.  Did I mention that you should fix the data so a *date* is stored as a `date`?

Comment: Okay, Maybe I am not aware of this, Is it possible that the datatype for a column is **date** and it has more than one date formats in the values as mentioned in the question? If that is the case, I do not have to worry this scenario

Comment: @KanishkSrivastava . . . No.  That is not possible.  `date` uses an internal format.